# SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF needed on application server, but ALTER permission seems dangerous. Suggestion?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, web-applications, sql-server-2012

We are building a multi-user web app where they need an unique `postId` for `post` they create.  Each `post` has `(userId, postId)` as the compound primary key.

Right now, `postId` is an identity value, but because of the need to support some operations that require `postId` to be inserted as is (no re-numbering), we decide to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF`.

However, our DBA told us that such operation is not meant be used by the application server because the ALTER permission requirement:

> **Permissions**
>
> User must own the table or have ALTER permission on the table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms188059.aspx

If the application server got hacked, with ALTER permission it seems rather risky.  Our DBA suggests us to not use identity value at all, and locally generate an unique `postId` per user.

Can `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` be left on globally?

If it can't be left on globally, does avoiding identity value and use local generation of `postId` (per user) with `max(postId)+1` per user make sense?  We much prefer to use identity value if possible because we are worried about possible deadlocks and performance issues associated with custom postId generation.

Comment: Why don't you simply make them UUIDs?  Also, having the userID as part of the primary key seems unnecessary.

Comment: @DanBracuk having userID as part of the PK because if I want to copy user A posts to user B, I can do that easily without reassigning postID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with SQL Server 2012 you can use [sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) like in Oracle. You may be better off with those. First, create the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySeq AS LONG START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
GO
```

Then have the table's primary key default to the next sequence value (instead of being an IDENTITY value):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
   myPK LONG PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR mySeq),
   myWhatever...
);
```

If you don't specify a PK value with an `INSERT` you'll get a unique, generated sequence value. It's basically the same behavior as an `IDENTITY`. But if you want to specify a PK value you can, as long as you don't violate the primary key's uniqueness - but again, that's the same behavior as an `IDENTITY` with `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON`.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this will work indeed if it works like having `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON` enabled all the time.  Anything one should watch out for with using SEQUENCE?

Comment: I came here to say this (more or less). My only quibble: name the default constraint! It doesn't take that much and makes automated schema comparison so much easier.

Comment: @BenThul - I agree; I was just trying to keep the answer as stripped-down as possible. I name all constraints except for NOT NULL.

Comment: @Henry - there are a couple differences, summarized very nicely in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16472498/2091410). The differences can cause a gap in sequence numbers. They've never been deal-breakers for me. Also, note that I've update the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement: I got sloppy and put `END WITH 1`, which is meaningless - I meant to put `INCREMENT BY 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to evaluate your database design if this is possible.  A post should be a fixed entity and an identity column as a single primary key should be sufficient. In your comment you mentioned that you might want to copy posts from one user to another user.  If you want to split the post so that user1 and user2 can independently control their own versions of the post, then it's just a matter of copying all the post attributes into a new record (which creates a new identity key) and then updating the new records user attribute from User1 to User2.  But if you want the users to share the same post... then you should do that with a relationship from user to post to avoid the need to maintain duplicate data in your post table.  In other words, if you want to assign user1 and user2 to an **identical version** of the post, then create a relationship table with two fields (Post ID, User ID).  This way you can simply add a user to the post by inserting a new record into the relationship table.

Example:  Post 1 is owned by user 1.  Post 2 is owned by user 1 and 2.

```
 Post Table - Key (Post ID)
 (Post ID=1, PostText="This post is important!")
 (Post ID=2, PostText="This post is also important!")

 Users - Key (User ID)
 (User ID=1, Name="Bob")
 (User ID=2, Name="George")

 Post Users - Key (Post ID, User ID)
 (Post ID=1, User ID=1)
 (Post ID=2, User ID=1)
 (Post ID=2, User ID=2)
```

Comment: The post is just the root node.  It has many complicated one-to-many relationships, therefore if the post ID is kept the same, it'd be easy to just update the userID part using insert with select subquery.  Otherwise, we will need to rely on the application server to keep track of a translation map (old IDs -> new IDs), and insert rows with new IDs one at a time.

Comment: I hope you do not dismiss this out of hand. The fact that the primary key is defined as (userId, postId) is concerning. The identity column is by definition a unique field identifying the record, so adding the user id breaks second normal form. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form for more explanation. Trying to use identity_insert is also concerning. It exists to support data migrations and maintenance, not normal operations. It requires elevated permissions as well. If you add context to your question as to why you need it, maybe we can help you find a way to eliminate it.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I think having the pk to be compound (userId, postId) already satisfies "unique field identifying the record".  I know the use of identity_insert is concerning, therefore I'm leaning towards trying the new Sequence support in 2012 so that the web application does not need to be grant the Alter Table permission.

Comment: As for why i don't copy the content of the post to another post with an identity value as PK, it is because with that approach a lot of re-numbering 's needed for the aggregates, whereas if userId is also part of the PK, I could just use insert with select subquery, and assign a new userId to it in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

This concerns me a little:

"...the need to support some operations that require postId to be inserted as is (no re-numbering)..."

I assume this sort of operation is the exception, and not the norm? I can also only assume that you're inserting the same post with the same Post ID into the same table without deleting the original? It's still not clear WHY you want to do this.

I really don't see why you'd need to worry about changing the Post ID if you're assigning posts to another user. Nothing else changes except the values in the User ID column by the sounds of it. Unless you mean you can have two or more posts with the same Post ID and the same User ID. If so, why?

To answer your questions:

1. No, IDENTITY_INSERT cannot be set globally. It is a per object, per session setting.
2. Using MAX(PostID) + 1 doesn't make sense. Is there a reason why IDENTITY(1, 1) doesn't work for the PostID column? You can re-seed if necessary.
3. Don't use application-generated UUIDs as key values. They make queries so much slower. At worst, use NEWSEQUENTIALID() in SQL Server if you absolutely want to use a UUID. UUIDs unnecessarily bloat tables and indexes, and with the exception of NEWSEQUENTIALID, are query performance killers.
4. What you could do is have a Primary key column simply called ID, and then a surrogate key called Post ID if that needs to be non-unique. That way, when you copy a post, the copy of the original gets a new ID, but still retains the original Post ID, but with no need to worry about doing anything unnecessary to the PK.

However, without any changes to the application or the DB, what I would suggest is using a stored procedure executed as the owner of the stored proc (which also owns the Posts table) to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON only when absolutely necessary. Here is an example I've just written:

```
create procedure dbo.sp_CopyPost
(
    @PostID     INT
    ,@UserID    INT
)
with execute as owner
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    set identity_insert dbo.Posts on;

    begin tran
        insert into dbo.Posts
        (
            PostID
            ,UserID
            --Whatever other columns
        )
        values
        (
            @PostID
            ,@UserID
            --Whatever other values
        )
    commit tran

    set identity_insert dbo.Posts off;

    select @@IDENTITY
end
```

That will do what you want, based on the current wording of your question, and the comments you've made.

If you need to essentially "plug the gaps" in your identity column, you will find Microsoft-recommended queries to do so in section B here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: The application needs to clone a deep copy of an root entity and its aggregates to another user (userId) in the same table.  The reason we chose to use userId and postId together as compound PK is because we can then use insert with select subquery on the sql server by providing the target userId, without looping through inserts one by one on the application layer.  Also, with compound PK it is more efficient to satisfy `where userid=x and postid=y` with the clustered index.   Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks!